# Text::ParseWords->quotewords() does not work in case of single quote in a string in perl

Tags: perl

I tried something like this :

```
use Text::ParseWords;

my $var="Id;Id2;my name 'is Ankit;code";

my @temp = quotewords('\;',1,$var);

my $length = scalar @temp;

print "$length\n";
```

I can use split()  but it does not work in case of - "Id;Id2;"my name is ;Ankit";code". Any suggestions ?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: expected output is 4

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the single quote.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::ParseWords;
my $var = q{Id;Id2;my name \'is Ankit;code};
my @words = quotewords('\;', 0, $var);
print scalar @words; #prints 4
```

Comment: Thanks , seems to work ...... have to add a escape character every time i face this ....let me try this

Comment: What if i am unable to use q{} , suppose i want to read $var from the contents of the file and then replace "'" with "\'". Please suggest

Comment: You could use search and replace. `$var =~ s!"!\\"!`